# How to achieve an enumeration of texts with borders

Tags: tcolorbox

How to achieve a layout just like the attached image. I have tried already using `tcolorbox` but the items are shown one per line.

```
\newcommand{\codebox}[1]{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=45{
\begin{tcolorbox}[hbox]{#1}\end{tcolorbox}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `tcolorbox` environments start a new line, `\tcbox` commands doesn't

Comment: The word `enumeration` is wrong here, in my point of view

Answer (score 8):

`tcolorbox` environments start a new line, `\tcbox` doesn't and can be placed one after another one in a line etc.

The options try to get the look (change the color etc. to one feelings) and apply `equal height group` in order to guarantee that the boxes have the same height -- compile twice for this in order to get the correct heights here!)

See also how local boxes can be changed by adding options to the `\codebox` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\definecolor{blueboxcolor}{rgb}{0.28,0.52,0.77}% Kolorpicker from KDE suggests this color mixture

\tcbset{%
  bluecolorbox/.style={
  enhanced,  
  frame hidden, 
  colback=blueboxcolor,
  colupper=white,
  nobeforeafter,
  boxsep=0pt,
  arc=4pt,
  auto outer arc,
  halign=center,
  fontupper=\ttfamily\LARGE\bfseries
}
}


\newtcbox{\codebox}[1][]{
  bluecolorbox,
  equal height group,
  #1,
}


\begin{document}
\parindent=0em
\codebox{Swift} \codebox{Objective C} \codebox{Java} \codebox{C++} \codebox{\LaTeXe} \codebox{Fortran 54} \codebox{Algol} \codebox{Pascal} \codebox{QBasic} \codebox{HTML} \codebox[colback=yellow!60,colupper={blue}]{\TeX} \codebox{Eiffel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{codebox/.style={% set whatever defaults you want for the style
    rounded corners,
    fill=blue,
    text=white,
    rectangle,
    inner sep=1mm,
    minimum height=5mm,
    font=\ttfamily
  }
}

% usage: \codebox[optional style]{text}
\newcommand{\codebox}[2][]{\tikz{\node[codebox,#1]at(0,0){#2};)}}

\begin{document}

  \codebox{Swift} \codebox{Objective-c}
  \codebox[fill=red]{MySQL} \codebox[fill=green]{Python}

\end{document}
```

Apologies for the choice of colours! :)